# Most efficient way to find first match in batch of regexes for pcre library

Tags: c++, c, pcre

There are quite a few ways to tweak the pcre library,  and I have been pondering for some time on the most processing efficient way to match against a list of regexes.

In my use case I only care about getting a match, I would like to stop after the first match, and I do not care about the content of the match.  I realise for this I can use the `match_limit`.

Performance is important.

The regexes are provided as a list, and I could "or" them together into a single regex. `(?:(?:regex1)|(?:regex2))` or some such, but this could be problematic, I might end up having to compile a particularly long string, and duplicate memory usage as I build the string, this feels nasty, and I'm not sure how performant it would be vs matching a list of compiled pcre, I guess I should benchmark.

I'll write some benchmarks, and test as best as I can the following techniques:

1. Concatenate regex into one large regex.
2. Compile the regex separately - match list of regex sequentially
3. Compile the regex separately - match list in parallel worker threads

Am I missing something? I can imagine that compiling into a single large regex might offer some optimizations vs doing multiple matches.

Really looking for someone with some experience and expertise to guide me in the right direction here.

Comment: If you want to optimize for speed, a single regex will likely give the best results. If you want to optimize for memory usage, using a list of small-ish regexes will probably be the best. Pick one, but not both. P.S., multiple regexes, and parallel threads, is a good idea.

Comment: Have you seen [re2](https://github.com/google/re2)?  Particularly the [RE2::Set](https://github.com/google/re2/blob/master/re2/set.h) interface might be interesting to you: An RE2::Set represents a collection of regexps that can be searched for simultaneously.

Comment: @e.dan I hadnt seen re2, but I'm suddenly very interested, many thanks for the pointer, I'll look into it.

Comment: *"I guess I should benchmark"* - you guessed right :) BTW I'm curious about your results, so I'd appreciate if you could update your post once you have them.

Comment: I will do, it'll take me a little while, currently playing with re2, I'll include that in my benchmarks.

Comment: All things being equal, it's usually the longest match takes the longest time to complete. I say all things being equal because, the race has to start at the same position. For example  `a.+` will take much longer (relatively) than `a.`. They both start at the same point, but in this case they needn't. So, since alternations are handled left to right, the first one at the character position always kicks it off and will return on sucess, you really can't get around that.